# Count repeated values in a specific column in a CSV file and return the value to another column (python2)

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

I am currently trying to count repeated values in a column of a CSV file and return the value to another CSV column in a python.

For example, my CSV file :

```
KeyID    GeneralID
145258   KL456
145259   BG486
145260   HJ789
145261   KL456
```

What I want to achieve is to count how many data have the same `GeneralID` and insert it into a new CSV column. For example,

```
KeyID    Total_GeneralID
145258   2
145259   1
145260   1
145261   2
```

I have tried to split each column using the split method but it didn't work so well.

My code :

```
case_id_list_data = []

with open(file_path_1, "rU") as g:
    for line in g:
        case_id_list_data.append(line.split('\t'))
        #print case_id_list_data[0][0] #the result is dissatisfying 
        #I'm stuck here..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And if you are adverse to pandas and want to stay with the standard library:

**Code:**

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
with open('file1', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(reader)
    lines = [line for line in reader]
    counts = Counter([l[1] for l in lines])

new_lines = [l + [str(counts[l[1]])] for l in lines]
with open('file2', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(header + ['Total_GeneralID'])
    writer.writerows(new_lines)
```

**Results:**

```
KeyID   GeneralID   Total_GeneralID
145258  KL456   2
145259  BG486   1
145260  HJ789   1
145261  KL456   2
```

Comment: What python version are you using to import the collections library? I'm using python v 2.6.6 and I got an error,
`from collections import Counter`
`ImportError: cannot import name Counter`

Comment: Counter is 2.7+, but you can get the source here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/

Answer (score 3):

You have to divide the task in three steps:
 1. Read CSV file
 2. Generate new column's value
 3. Add value to the file back
    import csv
    import fileinput
    import sys

```
# 1. Read CSV file
# This is opening CSV and reading value from it.
with open("dev.csv") as filein:
    reader = csv.reader(filein, skipinitialspace = True)
    xs, ys = zip(*reader)

result=["Total_GeneralID"]

# 2. Generate new column's value
# This loop is for counting the "GeneralID" element.
for i in range(1,len(ys),1):
    result.append(ys.count(ys[i]))

# 3. Add value to the file back
# This loop is for writing new column
for ind,line in enumerate(fileinput.input("dev.csv",inplace=True)):
    sys.stdout.write("{} {}, {}\n".format("",line.rstrip(),result[ind]))
```

I haven't use temp file or any high level module like panda or anything.

Comment: Can you show another method for csv.DictReader? or is it the same thing?and what does `xs,ys = zip(*reader)` do?

Comment: Zip() returns a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
 from each of the argument sequences.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
#read your csv to a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('file_path_1')
#generate the Total_GeneralID by counting the values in the GeneralID column and extract the occurrance for the current row.
df['Total_GeneralID'] = df.GeneralID.apply(lambda x: df.GeneralID.value_counts()[x])
df = df[['KeyID','Total_GeneralID']]
Out[442]: 
    KeyID  Total_GeneralID
0  145258                2
1  145259                1
2  145260                1
3  145261                2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library:

- first [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
- get counts of values in column `GeneralID` by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), `rename` by output column
- [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file')
s = df['GeneralID'].value_counts().rename('Total_GeneralID')
df = df.join(s, on='GeneralID')
print (df)
    KeyID GeneralID  Total_GeneralID
0  145258     KL456                2
1  145259     BG486                1
2  145260     HJ789                1
3  145261     KL456                2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use csv.reader instead of split() method.
Its easier.

Thanks